# `pigz` (parallel `gzip`) saves no time over regular `gzip`

Tags: centos, performance, compression, gzip, parallelism

I'm using `pigz` (parallel `gzip`) to backup my data, but there's no increase in performance -- both `pigz` and regular `gzip` take about 13 hours to compress my 260GB of data to 26GB. Why isn't the parallel `gzip` (`pigz`) saving any time?

---

The server has 5 CPUs running and by default `pigz` utilizes all of the cores, I can see `pigz` processes using 7 threads. The server has 14 GB of RAM though most of it is cached with 13.8 GB RAM leaving it with 200 MB memory, disk space is sufficient. Where else can I check because `pigz` is running well but does not complete faster as I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the specs of your system it's hard to say why. Three possibilities come to mind:

- Your `pigz` process has only access to one cpu core. Then it can't be faster than non-parallel gzip.
- Disk throughput is the limiting factor.
- main memory is too limited (although that seems unlikely)

Check these first, of course there might be other causes that I didn't think about.